# Connecting users to cloud firestore

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, pyrebase

I'm trying to sign users in to my cloud firestore database using pyrebase but I'm getting an error message ```AttributeError: 'Database' object has no attribute 'collection'. Does pyrebase work with firestore or just the real time database?

I found this link, which is the exact question I have but doesnt have an answer [How to connect users to Firestore through Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56534982/how-to-connect-users-to-firestore-through-python?r=SearchResults)

If pyrebase only works with the  RTB how do you sign users in to the firestore? (The only tutorial I've found is about signing in using the admin SDK but I want client side code)

```
import pyrebase

config = {
    "apiKey": "",
    "authDomain": "",
    "databaseURL": "",
    "projectId": "",
    "storageBucket": "",
    "messagingSenderId": "",
    "appId": "",
    "measurementId": ""
}

firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
storage = firebase.storage()
auth = firebase.auth()
db = firebase.database()

email = input("Email : ")
password = input("Password : ")

auth.create_user_with_email_and_password(email, password)

data = {
    u'name': u'Los Angeles',
    u'state': u'CA'
    }

db.collection(u'cities').document(u'LA').set(data)
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error message.

Comment: I've added in a MRE